# Why my Model has a low MAE and low R2 score at the same time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to build a CNN regression model. The input data is satellite images for 10 years.

The input shape is `[10, 256,256, 10]` which represents `[Year, Image shape, Image Shape, Channels/Bands]`

The output of the model is a number between 0-1 which is the percentage value of the area in the image.

these are the parameters used

```
CHANNELS=5
BATCH_SIZE=16
INPUT_SHAPE=(10,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,CHANNELS)
SAMPLES=100
LR=1e-7
EPOCHES=10
```

I'm using the Conv3D layer as an input layer as it provides the ability to provide volume data to the model, and the Dense layer as output.

```
Model: sequential_FLATTEN_100_5_16_SGD_1e-07_30_v1
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv3d_3 (Conv3D)            (None, 10, 254, 254, 32)  1472      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_3 (MaxPooling3 (None, 10, 127, 127, 32)  0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_4 (Conv3D)            (None, 10, 125, 125, 64)  18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_4 (MaxPooling3 (None, 10, 62, 62, 64)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)          (None, 2460160)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_24 (Dense)             (None, 256)               629801216 
_________________________________________________________________
dense_25 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 257       
=================================================================
Total params: 629,821,441
Trainable params: 629,821,441
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

This model gives the following score on the Training set:

```
mean_absolute_error: 0.09013315520024737
mean_squared_error: 0.11449361186977994
explained_variance_score: -0.2407465861253424
r2_score: -0.9382254392540899
```

[image: Training data actual vs prediction plot model 1]

And on the Validation set:

```
mean_absolute_error: 0.1923245317002776
mean_squared_error: 0.2579017795812263
explained_variance_score: -5.067052299015521
r2_score: -5.4177061135705475
```

[image: Validation data actual vs prediction plot model 1]

I also tried a different model as follow:
In this only the first layer is Conv3D and the rest are Dense layers

```
Model: "sequential_FLATTEN_100_5_16_Adam_1e-07_30_v1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv3d_1 (Conv3D)            (None, 4, 250, 250, 32)   54912     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_1 (MaxPooling3 (None, 1, 83, 83, 32)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 220448)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 512)               112869888 
_________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 256)               131328    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)             (None, 128)               32896     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 32)                2080      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_21 (Dense)             (None, 16)                528       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_22 (Dense)             (None, 8)                 136       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 9         
=================================================================
Total params: 113,100,033
Trainable params: 113,100,033
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Which gave me the following score on the Training set:

```
mean_absolute_error: 0.08475626941395917
mean_squared_error: 0.1637630610914996
explained_variance_score: 0.19943303382780664
r2_score: 0.19214565669613703
```

[image: Training data actual vs prediction plot model 2]

And on the Validation set:

```
mean_absolute_error: 0.15135902269457854
mean_squared_error: 0.2650686092962602
explained_variance_score: -1.7471740284409094
r2_score: -1.7776585146674124
```

[image: Validation data actual vs prediction plot model 2]

As you can see the model has very low MAE and MSE but the R2-Score and Explained-Variance-Score are also low at the same time.

How can I improve these results?.
Also when the sample size is increased the model starts to predict similar values for all inputs.

Answer (score 2):

I just notice the number of parameters so huge for such task. May be suffering from [Vanishing or Exploding gradient](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-vanishing-exploding-gradient-problem-in-deep-neural-networks-191358470c11). Try to reduce the feature extractor dimension as small as possible. You may in-between apply dropout and regularization as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look here:
https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat462/node/170/

Answer (score 0):

If the red line denotes the prediction line by the model, then I think your code lacks some optimization to generalize the prediction more, in essence it should be a curve at least. Refer below url which is a tutorial of CNN regression:

https://www.datatechnotes.com/2019/12/how-to-fit-regression-data-with-cnn.html?m=1

In above tutorial, the output graph is generalized, which reduces the error. You can try the dame steps perhaps.